# Is there a way to create a plumber API in R with no parameters?

Tags: r, api, plumber

I'm trying to return just a string or a data frame as soon as the API is pinged by the user. I'm using plumber to create this API. Unfortunately, I keep on getting a 404 error when I try to do this. Is this possible in plumber?

```
library(plumber)

#* Test plumber of API with no parameters
#* @response default array with corresponding responses
#* @serializer unboxedJSON
#* @post /Test


function(){
 
  return("Hello World!")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Save your script as plumber_test.R, then open an R session and type

```
> library(plumber)
> reply_service <- pr('plumber_test.R')
> pr_run(reply_service, port=9494, host='127.0.0.1')
```

In another terminal try

```
$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:9494/Test
```

And you should get back `["Hello World!"]`